# VBA Excel merging column when looping doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to batch-merge my columns.

The following code:

```
 Dim frrngr as Range
 Set frrngr = .Range("E18:K26")
 Dim k As Long
 Dim j As Integer

 For j = 1 To frrngr.Rows.Count Step 2
                With frrngr.Cells(RowIndex:=j 'Columnindex:=1)
                    .Merge
                    .Interior.ColorIndex = 2
                    .BorderAround ColorIndex:=1, Weight:=xlThin
                End With
 Next
```

doesn't work as expected. I can't merge columns despite using the `.Merged` option.
Even when the `Columnindex:=1` is removed it still doesn't work well

As per the following solution:
https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-merge-cells-loop.1081023/
I could be able to make the merging in the loop.

What is wrong then?

Comment: Not clear for me what you try doing... Do you try merging column E:E of `frrngr`? If not, please describe **in words** what you mean by "merging column" and "as expected".

Comment: You're aware if you merge columns that only the first value remains in the merged cells? If you want all of the values to remain, you'll need a bit more clarity in your question as what needs to happen.

Comment: @FaneDuru i would like to merge the columns with the frrngr range in the loop with step 2, like E18:K18, E20:K20, E22:K22 and so forth.

Comment: Then, see the code I posted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code currently "merges" only single cells. With the `Cells`-property of a Worksheet or a Range, you can address only single cells. When giving only one parameter (eg `.Cells(3)`, you get the nth (in this case 3rd) cell - starting to count at the top left cell. When giving 2 parameters (eg `.Cells(3, 2)`, you address a cell by row and column number. But you always get only one single cell. For more information, see the [Microsoft documentation](https://see%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.cells)

When you want to merge several cells, you have to specify the range that defines those cells - there are several ways to so. The following code will use the [Resize](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize)-Method.

Now you missed to tell *which* cells you want to merge. The following will merge all cells of a row from your range `frrngr`

```
With frrngr.Cells(j, 1).Resize(1, frrngr.Columns.Count)
    .Merge
    (...)
End With
```

Merging 2 cells that are on top of each other would be

```
With frrngr.Cells(j, 1).Resize(2, 1)
    .Merge
End With
```

And merging 2 cells of 2 rows of that range would be

```
With frrngr.Cells(j, 1).Resize(2, frrngr.Columns.Count)
    .Merge
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next way:

```
Sub MergeTwoRangeColumns()  
 Dim frrngr As Range, j As Long

 Set frrngr = Range("E18:K26")

 For j = 1 To frrngr.rows.count Step 2
    With frrngr.rows(j)
        .merge
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 2
        .BorderAround ColorIndex:=1, Weight:=xlThin
    End With
 Next
End Sub
```